# Where to place Firestore detach listener methods in vue.js app

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm developing a vue app where i set several Firestore listeners. I want to detach these Firestore listeners when the user closes the browser tab or navigates away from my app.

I call the detach methods in beforeUnmount lifecycle event. But i can't tell if the detach methods complete before the browser window closes.

So, my question is what is the best practice for detaching Firestore listeners in a vue js app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) browser event

```js
created () {    
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.detachFireStoreListener)  
},
methods: {
  detachFireStoreListener () {
    //detach FirestoreListenern here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is an older version ... here's the updated one.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```